# How to covert set to String?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-admin

I have a model and I am returning the function using `@property`, but it's giving me data in the set, and I want this data in a string with a comma, please let me know how I can do it.

Here is my `models.py` file:

```py
class ShippingAddress(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    zipcode = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.address

    @property
    def Address(self):
        return str(self.address), str(self.state), str(self.zipcode)
```

And here is my `admin.py` file, where is am calling the function:

```py
class ShippingAddressAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display=['city','state','Address']
    readonly_fields=['city','Address']
admin.site.register(ShippingAddress, ShippingAddressAdmin)
```

The output of `@property` function is this:

```
('House number-69, sector-55, Gurugram', 'Haryana', '122002')
```

Comment: You return a tuple of strings. You should do something like this: `return f'{self.address}, {self.state}, {self.zipcode}'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the Python [f-string](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) to format it how you want.

For example, you could change
`return str(self.address), str(self.state), str(self.zipcode)`
to
`return f'{self.address}, {self.state}, {self.zipcode}'`

Comment: No, f-strings use the method `__str__` by default, so you don't need to call `str()`

Comment: @VaclavPelc Thanks for clearing that out. I edited my solution accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Return like this
",".join(your set)
This will join all set values separate by comma